# How to define this route in route.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use ajax call in my javascript:

```
var myUrl = "/cars/customer_cars"     
$.getJSON(
       myUrl,  
       {car_id: car_id, customer_id: customer_id},
       function(data) {
           //Deal with response data
       }
);
```

From browser's point of view, `myUrl` will be some thing like "**/cars/customer_cars?car_id=3&customer_id=6**", the `car_id` and `customer_id` values are depending on user's selection on the page. That's two variables. When this ajax request is sent, I would like it to call a controller function, so I need to configure `myUrl` in **route.rb**

(Something like

`match /cars/customer_cars?car_id=?&customer_id=? , :to =>"cars#some_function"`. I just don't know the syntax of this configuration.

So, when the request is sent, **CarsController**'s **some_function** will be called.

How to configure `myUrl` in route.rb???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gan simply use:

```
get "/cars/customer_cars" => "CarsController#some_function"
```

the variables will be accessible through `params[:car_id]` and `params[:customer_id]`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider having routes like that:

```
resources :customers do
  resources :cars do
     member do
       get :some_function 
     end
  end
end
```

So that you can have links like

```
link_to "customer car", some_function_customer_car_path(customer, car)
```

which would translate to

```
/customers/:customer_id/cars/:id
```

Then you wouldnt need to pass data in your $.getJSON, just the url, and in your controller, you can get params[:id] and params[:customer_id].

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $.getJSON(
      $(this).attr("href"),  
      {},
      function(data) {
       //Deal with response data
      }
    );
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Maybe it doesnt answer exactly your question, but you should think about it. It's not good to have the urls in your javascript in my opinion.